# The Riemannian metric on manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold with non-empty boundary and $DM$ is the double of $M$, is there a Riemannian metric $G$ on $DM$ such that $g=i^*G$? ($i$ is the inclusion from $M$ to $DM$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally there isn't a natural one, although metrics do exist.  There is *no* such Riemann metrics if you demand $i^* G = g$ for *both* inclusions of $M$ in its double.  For example, consider the flat disc $D^2$.  Having a metric on the double $S^2$ that restricts to two flat discs would violate the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.  But in the world of metric spaces, there are *metrics* on the double, they're just not Riemann metrics.

Comment: But if we require only one inclusion such that $i^*G=g$, then it seems to me that we can use partition of unity to construct $G$ on $DM$.

Comment: Yes, it just won't be a natural metric -- by that I mean it will depend on your choice of partition of unity.